# How to use AsyncStorage in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an Android App in React-Native.

This is my question:

I have basically 5 pages to manage the user:

1) Authentication ( in which I give the possibility to go to the Login or the SignUp)

2) Login Page

3) SignUp Page. In this page i set the value and then they are passed to the userPage.

4) User page. In this page I have the fetch to do a signup.

5) HomepageUser

In the User page I have the 2 function :

> AsyncStorage.setItem
>
> AsyncStorage.getItem

Like this

```
static async saveLoggedInUser(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@loggedInUser", JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  static async getUserLoggedIn() {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@loggedInUser");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Now My First page is the Authentication, how can I check if an user is already authenticated and then direct it to the HomepageUser??

Thanks you a lot!

Comment: which routing/ navigation method you are using in the app?

Answer (score 0):

On successful login you need to set user token in the Sign in page,

```
try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', usertoken);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
```

Inside the componentDidMount method of your first page you need to check whether user token is set or not,

```
componentDidMount = async() =>{
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
```

}

if token exist navigate to Home page or redirect to Sign in page.

There is an excellent documentation on Authentication flows with React navigation. You can check that if you are using React navigation for routing.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: thank you for your reply, I don't use React Navigation but router-flux :( It is similar about the process?